# Get difference in top 2 salary of employee from each department

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple employee table where i need to find difference between max of two salary in each department with maximum rank.
Table columns i have:
`dept`,`sal`,`rank`

Sample data could be

```
Dept        Sal     Rank
Finance     10000   1
Finance     20000   2
Finance     11000   1
Finance     15000   3
Finance     45000   4
Finance     42000   4
Operations  17000   1
Operations  12000   1
Operations  15000   2
Operations  19000   2
```

Desired output is

```
Dept        Diff    Rank
Finance     3000    4
Operations  4000    2
```

I have managed to fetch top 2 record in a very very inefficient way.
I am using mysql server.

Here is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   emps s
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    emps  f
            WHERE f.dept = s.dept AND 
                  f.rank >= s.rank
        ) <= 2
```

I need further help to get the output.

Comment: See the added tag.  Or see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the following query a try:

```
SELECT Dept, MAX(Rank) AS Rank,
       SUM(CASE 
              WHEN rnk = 1 THEN Sal 
              WHEN rnk = 2 THEN -Sal 
              ELSE 0
           END) AS diff
FROM (
   SELECT @rnk := IF(@dept = Dept, @rnk + 1,
                     IF(@dept := Dept, 1, 1)) AS rnk,
          Dept, Sal, Rank                  
   FROM emp
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @dept = '') AS vars
   ORDER BY Dept, Rank DESC, Sal DESC) AS t
GROUP BY Dept
```

The query uses variables to assign a rank number to each record depending on `Rank` and `Sal` values. The outer query consumes the variable values and performs *conditional aggregation* to calculate the difference between the first and the second ranking records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f4be/4)

Comment: thank you. I have no idea how this particular query worked. But i will and debug every line of it asap to understand. If required will bug you again. Thanks again.

Comment: would you please explain whats happening here ... its amazing